# Dividing rows into dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to get the list for the food from the database into array order by category so that I can split each entry into the categories.

Like this..

```
$menu = array(
    'Appetizers' => array(
        'Chicken Tenders' => '$2.99',
        'Twisted Chips' => '$1.99'
    ),
    'Seafood' => array(
        'Bayou Tilapia' => '$4',
        'Grill Atlantic Salmon' => '$3.99'
    ),
    'Steaks & Combos' => array(
        'Cowboy Grande Sirloin' => '$7.99'
    )
        )
```

Here is what I did.

```
$db->Query("SELECT menuTitle,menuCategory,menuPrice FROM menu");
$menu = array();
while ($row = $db->Row()) {
    $a = array($row->menuCategory => array($row->menuTitle=>$row->menuPrice));
    array_push($menu,$a);
    }
```

It doesn't seem to work. Would you please advise how to achieve this?

Comment: what does var_dump($menu); show

Comment: try $menu[$row->menuCategory][$row->menuTitle]=$row->menuPrice; instead of array_push and $a=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace:

```
$a = array($row->menuCategory => array($row->menuTitle=>$row->menuPrice));
array_push($menu,$a);
```

with:

```
$menu[$row->menuCategory][$row->menuTitle]=$row->menuPrice;
```

Comment: Wow, I've been trying to do it for hours. Thank you so much :D

Answer (score 0):

The code in the `while` block is not exactly seeming right, as you always **redefine** the `$a` array while iterating.

```
while ($row = $db->Row()) {
    $a[ $row->menuCategory ][ $row->menuTitle] = $row->menuPrice;
    array_push($menu,$a);
}
```

This way, you will only append new keys to the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
$db->Query("SELECT menuTitle,menuCategory,menuPrice FROM menu");
$menu = array(); $a = array();

while ($row = $db->Row()) {
    $a[$row->menuCategory ][$row->menuTitle] = $row->menuPrice;
}
array_push($menu,$a);

echo "<pre>";print_r($menu);echo "</pre>";
```